# What is the name of these class of graphs?

Tags: graph-theory

Given a graphs $G$ with vertex set $V$ and edge set $E$, I am defining a new graph $M(E)$ whose vertex set is $E$ and I define two vertices in $M(E)$ are adjacent if they share a common vertex in $G$. is there any name for this graph associated to the given graph $G$ ?

Thanks for your valuable timing.

Have a nice day.

Comment: @daw I cant find any reference in the name edge-dual graph. do you know any reference? thanks.

Comment: it's called the 'line graph', although this name is quite annoying to google for ... http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LineGraph.html

Comment: Thanks Gillian. I just found from my friends also.

Answer (score 1):

My friend just told me about this : 
The line graph L (G) of a graph G is what we are talking about whose definition can be found here : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph